# Bde Installer on these Embarcadero days

Tags: bde

Somebody could please tell me where I could find the good ol' BDE installer?

These links won't work anymore:

http://info.borland.com/devsupport/bde/bdeupdate.html

Answer (score 7):

http://www.jrsoftware.org/download.php/bdeinst.cab

Extract the archive and run:

```
regsvr32 BdeInst.dll
```

Comment: In my existing BDE folder (which installed with Delphi 5) there is a `bdeinst.txt` file that explains that basically this answer is right. That `bdeinst.cab` file linked in the answer is already in my `Borland Shared\BDE` folder. The instructions are for deploying BDE with an ActiveX (hence the CAB file). But you can copy that dll, register it, and you have BDE. Long story short: this is the correct way to ship the Borland Database Engine!

Answer (score 3):

Took months for me to realize there's nothing special about the BDE installation except for copying the files and adding the branches into the registy.  I use Actual Installer to build the project but these lines from the .aip file should help you understand just what to put in the registry.

Copy the BDE files into the respective folders and then copy these into the registry

```
0=<ProgramGroup>*?Uninstall <AppName>*?<InstallDir>\Uninstall.exe*?*?*?<InstallDir>*?*?0*?Normal
1=<ProgramGroup>*?<AppName>*?<InstallDir>\watch.exe*?*?*?<InstallDir>*?*?0*?Normal
[Registry]
0=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\BLW32*?BLAPIPATH*?STRING*?C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Borland Shared\\BDE*?Yes*?Yes
1=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine*?RESOURCE*?STRING*?0009*?Yes*?Yes
2=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine*?UseCount*?STRING*?37*?Yes*?Yes
3=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine*?SaveConfig*?STRING*?WIN32*?Yes*?Yes
4=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine*?DLLPATH*?STRING*?C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Borland Shared\\BDE*?Yes*?Yes
5=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine*?CONFIGFILE01*?STRING*?C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Borland Shared\\BDE\\IDAPI32.CFG*?Yes*?Yes
6=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\DRIVERS\PARADOX\INIT*?VERSION*?STRING*?4.0*?Yes*?Yes
7=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\DRIVERS\PARADOX\INIT*?TYPE*?STRING*?FILE*?Yes*?Yes
8=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\DRIVERS\PARADOX\INIT*?LANGDRIVER*?STRING*?DBWINUS0*?Yes*?Yes
9=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\DRIVERS\PARADOX\TABLE CREATE*?LEVEL*?STRING*?7*?Yes*?Yes
10=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\DRIVERS\PARADOX\TABLE CREATE*?BLOCK SIZE*?STRING*?32768*?Yes*?Yes
11=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\DRIVERS\PARADOX\TABLE CREATE*?FILL FACTOR*?STRING*?95*?Yes*?Yes
12=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\DRIVERS\PARADOX\TABLE CREATE*?STRICTINTEGRTY*?STRING*?TRUE*?Yes*?Yes
13=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\DATE*?SEPARATOR*?STRING*?/*?Yes*?Yes
14=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\DATE*?MODE*?STRING*?0*?Yes*?Yes
15=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\DATE*?FOURDIGITYEAR*?STRING*?FALSE*?Yes*?Yes
16=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\DATE*?YEARBIASED*?STRING*?TRUE*?Yes*?Yes
17=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\DATE*?LEADINGZEROM*?STRING*?FALSE*?Yes*?Yes
18=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\DATE*?LEADINGZEROD*?STRING*?FALSE*?Yes*?Yes
19=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\NUMBER*?DECIMALSEPARATOR*?STRING*?.*?Yes*?Yes
20=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\NUMBER*?THOUSANDSEPARATOR*?STRING*?,*?Yes*?Yes
21=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\NUMBER*?DECIMALDIGITS*?STRING*?2*?Yes*?Yes
22=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\NUMBER*?LEADINGZERON*?STRING*?TRUE*?Yes*?Yes
23=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\TIME*?TWELVEHOUR*?STRING*?TRUE*?Yes*?Yes
24=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\TIME*?AMSTRING*?STRING*?AM*?Yes*?Yes
25=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\TIME*?PMSTRING*?STRING*?PM*?Yes*?Yes
26=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\TIME*?SECONDS*?STRING*?TRUE*?Yes*?Yes
27=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\FORMATS\TIME*?MILSECONDS*?STRING*?FALSE*?Yes*?Yes
28=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?VERSION*?STRING*?4.0*?Yes*?Yes
29=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?LOCAL SHARE*?STRING*?FALSE*?Yes*?Yes
30=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?MINBUFSIZE*?STRING*?128*?Yes*?Yes
31=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?MAXBUFSIZE*?STRING*?2048*?Yes*?Yes
32=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?LANGDRIVER*?STRING*?DBWINUS0*?Yes*?Yes
33=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?MAXFILEHANDLES*?STRING*?48*?Yes*?Yes
34=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?SYSFLAGS*?STRING*?0*?Yes*?Yes
35=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?LOW MEMORY USAGE LIMIT*?STRING*?32*?Yes*?Yes
36=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?AUTO ODBC*?STRING*?FALSE*?Yes*?Yes
37=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?DEFAULT DRIVER*?STRING*?PARADOX*?Yes*?Yes
38=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?MEMSIZE*?STRING*?16*?Yes*?Yes
39=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?SHAREDMEMSIZE*?STRING*?2048*?Yes*?Yes
40=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*?SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT*?MTS POOLING*?STRING*?FALSE*?Yes*?Yes
```