# Where to download Delphi BDE 5.01

Tags: delphi, bde

Is it possible to download the BDE?

I have an old delphi app to support and the client has a new pc. I need to copy the EXE across and install the BDE on that machine.

Thanks

Comment: duplicate: [Bde Installer on these Embarcadero days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679806/bde-installer-on-these-embarcadero-days)

Comment: [This link](http://www.all2ezy.com/html/developer_downloads.html) is mentioned in [embarcadero's thread](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=53987&tstart=0)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, google knows some places like [here](http://www.prestwood.com/ASPSuite/KB/document_view.asp?qid=100537).

Comment: The first link worked well after using 10minutemail.com for a temporary email sign up thing. I can't speak for the second one.

Comment: File in second link contains a virus.

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to download it from the BDN/CDN, but I can't find it on Embarcadero's site.

Google BDE 5.2 DOWNLOAD and ye shall find it...

Answer (score 0):

> If you still want to install the BDE components perform these steps:
>   1.- Download the external BDE installer from your “My registered user
>   downloads” section:
>   http://cc.embarcadero.com/myreg
>   and complete the installation process

Source:

http://support.embarcadero.com/article/44082